# Merge to update all target table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the same table in 2 Databases

```
-----------------------------------
|           table                 |
-----------------------------------
| ID | col1 | col2 | ... | col(n) |
```

I need merge statement to update rows with matched IDs like this statement:

```
MERGE [DB1]..[table]
USING [DB2]..[table] ON [DB1]..[table].[ID] = [DB2]..[table].[ID]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET [DB1]..[table].[*] = [DB1]..[table].[*]
```

the problem is I have more than 30 columns so its difficult to set values column by column .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to use a wildcard character or keyword to specify the target update columns and mappings (even if all columns are identical). You can get a head start on all the typing by clicking on the `Columns` node in Object Explorer, and dragging it (and hence the column names) onto your query window:

> [image]
>
> [image]

So now you don't have all that much typing to do, just a bunch of manipulation and copying and pasting.

And I wouldn't use `MERGE` for this anyway, for various reasons (including the fact that the syntax is rather cumbersome when only an `UPDATE` is involved), and as mentioned in my comment above. [See this post for details](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and also [this landing page](https://sqlblog.org/merge).

```
UPDATE trg
  SET col1 = src.col1,
      col2 = src.col2, 
      ...
  FROM DB1.dbo.table AS trg
  INNER JOIN DB2.dbo.table AS src
    ON trg.ID = src.ID;
```

Generating that `UPDATE` statement (or any statement, really) dynamically, assuming all the column names and types are identical and compatible, is not all that difficult in T-SQL, unlike the wall of code apparently required in PL/SQL. Let's imagine you have these two matching tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table1(id int, a varchar(32), b date);
CREATE TABLE dbo.table2(id int, a varchar(32), b date);
```

Here is the dynamic SQL we could use (and half the complexity is just making sure it's pretty, protecting you from poorly chosen names, etc.):

```
DECLARE @TargetTable nvarchar(520) = N'dbo.table1',
        @SourceTable nvarchar(520) = N'dbo.table2',
        @JoinColumn  sysname       = N'id',
        @columns     nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @sql         nvarchar(max) = N'UPDATE trg SET ';

SELECT @columns += N',
         trg.'  + QUOTENAME(t.name) 
  + N' = src.'  + QUOTENAME(s.name)
FROM sys.columns AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS s
ON t.name = s.name
WHERE t.name <> @JoinColumn
AND t.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TargetTable)
AND s.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@SourceTable);

SELECT @sql += STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, N'') + N'
  FROM ' + @TargetTable + N' AS trg
    INNER JOIN ' + @SourceTable + N' AS src 
    ON trg.'    + QUOTENAME(@JoinColumn)
  + N' =  src.' + QUOTENAME(@JoinColumn) + N';';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Output:

```
UPDATE trg SET 
         trg.[a] = src.[a],
         trg.[b] = src.[b]
  FROM dbo.table1 AS trg
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS src 
    ON trg.[id] =  src.[id];
```

The join on `t.name = s.name` could be looser, e.g. if you know the mapping between the tables isn't precise, you could hard-code the mapping in that join, like `ON t.name = CASE WHEN t.name = N'foo' THEN s.name = N'bar' [...]` or you could store that mapping in a table and join to it, too.

If the objects are in different databases or even on different servers, it gets a little more complex, but not really. Imagine you have t1 and t2 in two different databases:

```
USE db1;
GO
-- target table:
CREATE TABLE dbo.table1(id int, a varchar(32), b date);
GO
USE db2;
GO
-- source table:
CREATE TABLE dbo.table2(id int, a varchar(32), b date);
```

You have to pick one of the databases to execute *from*, and the other database to run the dynamic SQL *in*. I'm choosing to execute dynamic SQL in the *source* database from the context of the *target* database. From different servers would be the same except there'd be a 4-part name instead of a 3-part name (and an assumption about a valid linked server, auth, etc).

```
USE db1; -- target!
GO

DECLARE @TargetDB       sysname       = DB_NAME(), -- assume local DB
        @TargetTable    nvarchar(520) = N'dbo.table1',
        @SourceDB       sysname       = N'db2',
        @SourceTable    nvarchar(520) = N'dbo.table2',
        @JoinColumn     sysname       = N'id',
        @columns        nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @sql            nvarchar(max) = N'UPDATE trg SET ',
        @exec           nvarchar(500),
        @execSQL        nvarchar(max),
        @TargetObjectID int;

SELECT @exec = QUOTENAME(@SourceDB) + N'.sys.sp_executesql',
       @TargetObjectID = OBJECT_ID(@TargetTable);

SET @execSQL = N'DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max) = SPACE(0);

  SELECT @columns += N'', trg.'' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
  + N'' = src.''  + QUOTENAME(s.name)
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDB) + N'.sys.columns AS t
INNER JOIN /* SourceDB is where it runs! */ sys.columns AS s
ON t.name = s.name
WHERE t.name <> @JoinColumn
AND t.[object_id] = @TargetObjectID
AND s.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@SourceTable);

SELECT @sql += STUFF(@columns, 1, 1, SPACE(0)) + N''
  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDB) + N'.' + @TargetTable + N' AS trg
    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@SourceDB) + N'.' + @SourceTable + N' AS src 
    ON trg.'' + QUOTENAME(@JoinColumn)
  + N'' =  src.'' + QUOTENAME(@JoinColumn) + N'';'';
  
PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql';
  
EXEC @exec @execSQL, N'@sql nvarchar(max),
  @JoinColumn sysname, 
  @TargetObjectID int, @SourceTable nvarchar(520)', 
  @sql, @JoinColumn, @TargetObjectID, @SourceTable;
```

Output is a little less pretty but similar to the original:

```
UPDATE trg SET  trg.[a] = src.[a], trg.[b] = src.[b]
  FROM [db1].dbo.table1 AS trg
    INNER JOIN [db2].dbo.table2 AS src 
    ON trg.[id] =  src.[id];
```

But, I mean, dragging the columns onto your query window (even twice) is a whole lot simpler. Sometimes you don't need to build a Rube Goldberg machine to put a query together.

Comment: I had no idea you could do that. Cool tip

Answer (score -3):

I think @AaronBertrand is right for this question. MERGE Statement is not required. You can just write simple update statement(with join if necessary).

1) Simple update

```
       UPDATE TableName
          SET col1 ='what you want to update'
```

2) Two or multiple Updates

```
  UPDATE t2
    SET t2.col2 =t.col2,
       t2.col3 =t1.col3,
       t2.col4 =t.col5

    FROM Table t 
    INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on t1.col1=t.col1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t2.col1=t1.col1
```